# Condição com Jquery: Adicionar atribudo quando não for uma determinada classe

Tags: jquery

No jQuery sei que:

```
$("#minhaDiv .classe").attr("display","block");
```

Exibe todos os elementos elementos filhos do elemento pai `#minhaDiv` que contém a classe `.classe`, mas não sei como fazer a condição de quando não for elementos com a classe.

Tenho diversos elementos `div` dentro de um formulário, e o `select` ao receber o evento [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) oculte todas as divs que não contém as classes `.classe`, o handler está feito, o [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) para verificar o valor do `select` e ocultar cada classe de acordo com o `option`.

Desconheço como ocultar todos os elementos filhos dentro de `#minhaDiv` que não contém a classe `.classe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o seletor [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) para isso:

```
$("#minhaDiv").find(":not(.classe)").show();
```

---

#### Exemplo

```js
let $container = $('#container');

$('#impares').on('click', function() {
    $container.children().show()
    $container.find(':not(.impar)').hide()
})

$('#pares').on('click', function() {
    $container.children().show()
    $container.find('.impar').hide()
})

$('#todos').on('click', function() {
    $container.children().show()
})
```

```css
#container > .item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.item.impar { background-color: gold !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="pares">Pares</button>
<button id="impares">Ímpares</button>
<button id="todos">Todos</button>

<hr>

<div id="container">
    <span class="item impar">1</span>
    <span class="item">2</span>
    <span class="item impar">3</span>
    <span class="item">4</span>
    <span class="item impar">5</span>
    <span class="item">6</span>
    <span class="item impar">7</span>
    <span class="item">8</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Fernando, como precisava, isso é novidade para mim, tentei pesquisar em inglês também mas não havia encontrado. abs